# Images don't display but TextView contents is correct

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application that displays a list of items when a tab is selected, then displays detail information about an item that was selected from the list :

Activity1
Tab1 -(intent)-> Activity 2: item1
    item2 -(intent)-> Activity 3: ImageView1
    item3       TextView1
     ...       ImageButton1
           ...

The details are to be displayed using ImageViews, ImageButtons, and TextViews.  The data comes from a database query, so the TextView text and ImageView drawables have to be assigned dynamically.

The correct text from the database query gets assigned to each of the Views.  I can see everything being added when I step through the code in the onCreate method of Activity3 in the debugger.

BUT, the drawables are only displayed when I select the first item in the ListActivity. If I select another item, all TextViews display the correct information but the drawables are not displayed for the ImageViews or ImageButtons.  It looks like only the backgrounds are being displayed.

The ImageButton drawables are not being dynamically assigned, only the ImageView drawables are.  The ImageButton drawables are set in the TableLayout XML that is associated with the activity.  Here is one entry :

```
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/row11" >
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/phonebutton"
 android:maxHeight="50px"
 android:maxWidth="50px"
 android:background="@drawable/ic_phone"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"     
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:src="@drawable/phoneselector" >
 </ImageButton >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/phonenumber"/>
```

(note - Originally, I had android_drawable="@drawable/ic_phone", then tried adding android:background="@drawable/ic_phone", and finally created the following selector (phoneselector.xml) :
 
       
       
       
    - end note)

If I select the first item again, its proper ImageView drawables are displayed along with the proper text in the TextViews.  The ImageView drawables that belong to the other items have no problems being displayed in Activity2's ListView.

The code successfully sets an onClickListener for the button (also in Activity3.onCreate).  If I click on what is displayed on the spot where the drawable should be, the phone number is dialed.

The code successfully sets an onClickListener for the button (also in DetailActivity.onCreate).

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I would appreciate any help figuring out what is wrong.

Here are more details because I wonder if the problem has to do with the use of the Views :

The Activity1 extends TabActivity and sets a TabHost view that contains a FrameLayout along with the TabWidget.  Activity1 creates the tabs dynamically.

Activity2 extends ListActivity and sets the content to its ListView (via setContentView(getListView()).

When ListActivity.onListItemClick is invoked (item in list is selected), a new Intent is created that contains an identifier in a Bundle and Activity3 is started.

The started activity (in Activity3.onCreate...) sets the content to a TableLayout view defined in a .xml file (via setContentView(R.layout.details.xml).

Here is the code from Activity3.onCreate :

Cursor c = null;

DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = null;

ImageButton button = null;
 TextView phoneText = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Resources res = getResources();
setContentView(R.layout.details);
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
Integer id = (Integer) bundle.getInt("id");
myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
c = myDbHelper.getWinery(id);
if (c != null) {  
    c.moveToFirst();
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.iconimage);
    String wholeString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PhotoIcon"));
    if (wholeString != null) { String[] splitString = wholeString.split(".jpg");
    String sString = splitString[0];
    int path = res.getIdentifier(sString, "drawable", "com.winerytour" );
    Drawable drawImage1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
    drawImage1.setVisible(true, true); //added to try to fix problem
    try {
        image1.setImageDrawable(drawImage1);
        image1.refreshDrawableState(););
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    image1.setAdjustViewBounds(true); }

    .. set other TextView text in same way ...

    phoneText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Telephone"));
    phoneText.setText(phone);
    button = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.phonebutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            performDial(); } });
    ((ImageButton) button).refreshDrawableState(); // attempt to fix problem
} // end c != null
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`content to its ListView (via setContentView(getListView()).` Don't do that. If you extend listactivity, the view is built it. If you don't want that, don't 'extend listview

Comment: I removed the statement.  The drawables are still not displayed, but at least my code is more correct. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Well I have no idea what the rest of your problem is since I can't read your code because it's poorly formatted, and I couldn't read any question in your original post. Also, don't do this `Integer id = (Integer) bundle.getInt("id")`

Comment: The code was formatted correctly when I copied it into the box for submission.  'Saw that it was garbled after the post.

Comment: This is my first post ever and I overlooked the "EDIT" button. Please excuse my clumsiness. I fixed the cast to Integer per your suggestion, Falmarri. The question that I have is "Why are the images not being displayed?"   Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your post is still extremely long and poorly formatted. Try to keep your question to 5-7 lines + code. I can't figure out which activity is supposed to display the images, or anything. Description of what your code is doing is not very helpful at all.

Comment: Activity 3 is trying to display the images in a TableLayout.I gave the background information because I thought that the view might not be displaying the images because I launched the Activity from an Activity that had been started by setting the content of a tab to an intent. Having learned more as I try to figure out what is wrong, I believe that that probably does not make a difference.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're experiencing versus what you're expecting

Comment: The example code is from the onCreate method of Activity 3 which is trying to display a drawable whose name comes from a database query and a drawable named in the XML. The query delivers data about an item that had been picked from a ListView in Activity2.  The Images are not shown if the picked item is not the first displayed in the list, although all text information is correct.  Since the text proves that the data was retrieved correctly, I guessed that the problem has to do with drawing the images.  I would be happy with any ideas as to how to find out what is happening.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm expecting both the images and the text to be displayed for any item picked from the list displayed by Activity2.

Comment: After getting past the idea that the use of the views was the cause, I took a hard look at the way I had defined the TableLayout, taking everything out and putting elements back in, one-by-one.  I suspect that the problem was that I had not enclosed the TableLayout in a LinearLayout, although I also encountered issues with individual elements as I added them back in.  It is working now.  I wonder why anything was displayed before !   Thank you VERY much for taking the time to try to help!